# How to increment max number of columns for a select statement **4096**

Tags: sql-server-2008, select

I would like to do a  `SELECT` Statement with more than `4096` different computations of a big table `>= 10 GB`. ([max is 4096](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx))

Is there a way to increment this value `4096` to `5100`. I am asking this because I would like to scan a huge table only once and avoid doing multiple select statements...

Comment: Doubt it. You could obviously concatenate some columns into one though and split them in your application.

Comment: could you explain a littlemore to get  the idea?

Comment: I've clarified martins comment in my answer

Comment: Rather than SELECT A,B,C,D....AA,AB,... I think Martin is suggesting SELECT A+'|'+B, C+'|'+D, .... then do a split on the receiving end, assuming A,B,C & D are string types, but it looks like you're doing aggregates, so that probably won't work for you.

Comment: correct, I amdoing aggregates on doubles, is there any other approach?

Comment: If you're doing this on doubles, then the only way is to convert the double to varchar, and then use your languages equivalent of Double.TryParse.

Comment: And the xml approach, could it be used...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was under the impression that these are hard-coded limits.

The first thought I had was, can you get around it with a union ?

Also, it might help to clarify your wording, are you trying to select > 4096 columns, or > 4096 different calculations ?

What about selecting to XML, does that make a difference ?

To expand on Martins comment, you could do this:

instead of

```
SELECT A, B, C
  FROM TestTable
```

try:

```
SELECT A + '||' + B, C
  FROM TestTable
```

Then in your application:

```
var joinedSelect = sqlDataReader[0].split("||");
string columnA = joinedSelect[0];
string columnB = joinedSelect[1];
```

Comment: I am doing aggregate functions on data (More than `> 4096 `)

Comment: If my data is floats I am gettinh this error: `Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 2
Error converting data type varchar to float.`

Comment: Ahh, yes you would in that scenario. You can only do this where the data types left and right are both varchar/nvarchar.  You could cast your floats to varchar though.